# How can I download an Adobe Connect recording as a video?

Tags: download, adobe, video-recording, adobe-connect

I have links to recorded online program, how can I download video from them?
When I try to download, I get this warning:

> You do not have permission to access this item. For further assistance, please check out the Adobe Connect support page.

I could not find a solution with the following methods:

1. Copy the “URL for Viewing” – Example, http://mycompany.adobeconnect.com/p12345678/
   Paste it into a new browser tab then add the following to the end of the URL: output/filename.zip?download=zip
   Your URL should look similar to this example, http://mycompany.adobeconnect.com/p12345678/output/filename.zip?download=zip
2. Download by copying the link to the website address (geometrixx.adobeconnect.com/ )

How can I download protected adobe videos?

Answer (score 1):

Below I share the steps on how to record the video you want to record with the screen recording option of the windows operating system:

1. Click to "**Windows Settings**"
2. Click to "**Games**"
3. Activate the "**XBox Game Bar**"(Open), (You will see record shortcuts Windows + Alt + G)
4. Click to "**Captures**" to update the longest video recording length
5. Click to "**Windows + Alt + G**" you will see the toolbar and update
   microphone settings, start the recording  by click the start button, then start the video which you want to record
6. Once you stop the recording and save, you can access the video recording from your "**Captures**" file.

Answer (score 0):

you can download 'Moyea Flv editor lite' and import the Cameravoip files and Sharescreens and attach them together and export Them as Flv video. now you can play it :)
not the easy way but the only way :(

the only files that matters are cameravoip.flv and sharescreen.flv  we don't need other files.

Comment: Write in steps. Attach supporting links if possible

Answer (score 0):

Hello
Adobe Connect files are not possible when you want to download it.
In other words, Adobe Connect saves its files as several parts of audio and video shared from the screen or webcam , also even if you want to get the exact playback time of each file, you have to look at the **indexstream.xml** file.
But due to a series of complexities, there are several different solutions first:

- Login to the site where the recorded link is located, then easily and without any problem, use the program I wrote to download your Adobe Connect session files,  for more details, refer to my github repository address and solve your problem .
  Also you can give your adobe connect recorded link to program and downloaded your files.
  But it goes without saying that if you need a text conversation, this program I wrote is not for you and the best solution for you is to film your screen.

https://github.com/HosseinShams00/AdobeConnectDownloader

- Record videos from your screen when the Adobe Connect  application is open

**But do not forget that in the before started process you must always be logged in to the site where you download the link of the recorded file**